# Pod has a restartable init container and the SidecarContainers feature is disabled

Tags: kubernetes

I am on v1.28 and trying to use the sidecar containers alpha feature (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#api-for-sidecar-containers). After adding the feature gate in the API, I am still not able to get the deployment to run. When creating a deployment, the pod remains in a pending state.

Here is the YAML for the deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: sidecar-demo
  name: sidecar-demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sidecar-demo
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: sidecar-demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: alpine:latest
        name: main
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'while true; do echo "logging" >> /opt/logs.txt; sleep 1; done']
        volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: /opt
      initContainers:
      - image: alpine:latest
        name: sidecar
        restartPolicy: Always
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'tail -F /opt/logs.txt']
        volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: /opt
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
```

When I run `kubectl describe po sidecar-demo`, I get the following warning under events

```bash
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  40s   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 Pod has a restartable init container and the SidecarContainers feature is disabled. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
```

I set the `sidecarContainers` feature gate to true in the API server manifest in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 172.30.1.2:6443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=172.30.1.2
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    - --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true
    image: registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.28.1
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 172.30.1.2
        path: /livez
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        host: 172.30.1.2
        path: /readyz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 50m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 172.30.1.2
        path: /livez
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ca-certificates
      name: etc-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki
      name: etc-pki
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priority: 2000001000
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-pki
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-share-ca-certificates
```

Comment: You not only have to add the feature gate in the API, you also need to add it to the kubelet configuration.

Comment: facing same after adding feature gate to kubelet config as well as restarting the kubelet daemon on each node. you have to update the kubelet config on each node.